# csv from subquery in IN() causes conversion error

Tags: sql-server

```
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        ISNULL(
            (
                SELECT
                    SUM (R.CALORIE)
                FROM
                    TA_RECIPE AS R
                WHERE
                        R.NO_RECIPE IN ([mp].recipe_ids)
                        OR R.NO_RECIPE IN ([tags2].recipe_ids)

            ),
            0
        ) AS caloriePerPortion
) AS [CAL]
```

The problem is in the part

```
R.NO_RECIPE IN ([mp].recipe_ids)
OR R.NO_RECIPE IN ([tags2].recipe_ids)
```

The recipe_ids contain comma seperated lists
when there's only one id in the recipe_ids it works fine but if there is actually a list in recipe_ids sql server interprets this as a varchar instead of a list of integers

wrapping them in STRING_SPLIT causes the query to become very slow (adds seconds to the execution time)

Comment: The problem here is not query performance it's your data model. Storing a list of atomic values - Ids - in a comma delimeted string is conflicting with basic relational data concepts. The solution is to change your data model so each recipe_id is stored as a single value; depending on how often your data changes, you could also use a pre-built table for this query which you maintain with a regular job, and you can then use this with an `in` or `exists` clause which will be orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: the data isn't stored as csv but was retrieved like that throug cross apply with for xml path
I changed it to
SELECT DISTINCT
 MM.MAP_ID AS mapId,
 MM.MENU_ID AS menuId,
 ...
 ...
 ...
 stuff((select ',' + CAST(RECIPES.recipe_ids AS VARCHAR(MAX)) for xml path('')), 1, 1, '') AS planningRecipe_ids
FROM MM
LEFT JOIN MP ON MM.MENU_ID = MP.MENU_ID
LEFT JOIN RECIPES ON RECIPES.PLANNING_MENU_ID = MP.PLANNING_MENU_ID

but then the for xml path doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

> wrapping them in STRING_SPLIT causes the query to become very slow

But that's the only way it can work.

```
select *
from t 
where c in ('1,2,3,4,5')
```

just doesn't do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

the data isn't stored as csv but was retrieved like that throug cross apply with for xml path

I changed it to

SELECT DISTINCT
MM.MAP_ID AS mapId,
MM.MENU_ID AS menuId,
stuff((select ',' + CAST(RECIPES.recipe_ids AS VARCHAR(MAX)) for xml path('')), 1, 1, '') AS planningRecipe_ids
FROM MM
LEFT JOIN MP ON MM.MENU_ID = MP.MENU_ID
LEFT JOIN RECIPES ON RECIPES.PLANNING_MENU_ID = MP.PLANNING_MENU_ID

but then the for xml path doesn't work